# How to style the material-ui slider

Tags: material-ui

I would like to set the colors of various parts of the slider,
the handle and both parts of the track: before and after the handle.
Or better still: make the slider invisible (but still working) so I can paint something myself based on the slider value...

I don't think the currently available style-property enables me to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, you can't do this just using the `style` property.

However you can change it's colors customizing the mui theme.
http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.0-alpha.2/#/customization/themes

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'material-ui/Slider';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/lib/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/lib/styles/getMuiTheme';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  slider: {
    trackColor: 'yellow',
    selectionColor: 'green'
  },
});

const SliderExample = () => (
  <div>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <Slider />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);

export default SliderExampleSimple
```

Note: The `handle` will have the same color as the line before it..(selectionColor)

Comment: Ok, this works. Just a minor correction: `import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/lib/MuiThemeProvider'` (no `/styles`)